# Proving that the Gamma function is a special function

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function

How can we prove that the Gamma function $\Gamma (x)$ is non-elementary? I know that the Liouville theorem proves whether or not an indefinite integral is non-elementary. So, we need a form of the Gamma function that can be expressed in terms of an indefinite integral. In a similar manner, how can we prove other special functions without an indefinite integral representation to be non-elementary (e.g: Riemann Zeta function, Hypergeometric functions, Bessel functions, etc), are not a combination of elementary functions?

Comment: there is a unique analytic continuation to the gamma function. The continuation has infinitely many poles and this is the problem.

Comment: This was proved by Hölder, see this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1424027). Concerning Liouvillian extensions see [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265780/how-to-determine-with-certainty-that-a-function-has-no-elementary-antiderivative/265884#265884).

Answer (score 0):

Euler proved that:
$$\Gamma (x)=\int_0^1(-\ln t)^xdt$$
[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Definition) shows that:
$$\zeta (s)=\frac{1}{\Gamma (s)}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}dx$$
[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel's_integrals) also shows that:
$$J_n(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi\cos (nt-x\sin t)dt$$
And once again, [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function#Euler's_integral_transform) shows a recursive integral formula for the Hypergeometric function, however, some forms of the Hypergeometric function *are* indeed elementary.

The Liouville theorem should be able to take it from there.

In terms of other functions without a known indefinite integral representation, I haven't but a clue at my disposal as to how to show whether or not they're elementary.